# Permanently sorting a table in SQLServer based on pre-existing data

Tags: sql-server, database, sorting

I have made a table in SQL Server based on pre-existing data:

```
SELECT pre_existing_data
INTO new_table
FROM existing_table
```

I am trying to get the output to permanently sort by a particular field once the table is created. I thought this would be as simple as adding an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of the chunk of code that makes the table, but the data still won't sort properly.

Comment: you can look into creating a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on the new_table.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to permanently sort a table in SQL.

You can create an index on the table and queries which use the index (in an ORDER BY clause) will be returned quicker, but the order the data is stored on the disk is not controllable.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an index-organized table by using a [CLUSTERED INDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx), which stores the data on disk in an ordered fashion on the clustering key. Then if you ORDER BY in your query based on the clustering key, data should come out very fast. Note that you have to use the ORDER BY in your query no matter what.

Comment: This is not exact -- a clustered index will store like data near to other similar data -- but it does not create an exact order.

Comment: True. Hence "ordered fashion" not "exact order". But for purposes of having a fast sort when using ORDER BY, it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

1. **I have made a new table on SQL Server on pre-existing Schema**

   ```
   insert into new_table
   select * from old_table
   ORDER BY col ASC|DSC;
   ```
2. **After it drop old_table and rename new table to old_table_name**

   ```
   drop table old_table_name;
   rename new_table_name to old_table_name;
   ```
3. Try this trick to short your data in the table permanently

Comment: That works very well and is useful!