# Store data sorted into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

Good afternoon all,

I have two columns that I am trying to sort into a table, memberid and then total spend.  When I run the following query:

```
Select Memberid, totalspend
from Table
order by totalspend;
```

my data returns the way that I expect it to.  When I try and run:

```
Select MemberID, TotalSpend
into SampleTable
from Table
order by TotalSpend
```

SQL does not retain the sort.

The research that I have done so far suggests that the select into statement should work but for some reason it it not.  I have tried converting the Totalspend to a float, int or varchar and still no luck.

I need my data sorted so that I can perform calculations on the table based on top x rows.

I am currently using SQL Server 2017.

Thank you,

Richard

Comment: In SQL Server tables , it does not matter in what order the rows are stored, if you need a sorted result set , use `ORDER BY` in your select queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently sorting a table in SQLServer based on pre-existing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645480/permanently-sorting-a-table-in-sqlserver-based-on-pre-existing-data)

Comment: The challenge that I am facing with that solution is that I have a column that I need to do a cumulative total on starting with the highest dollar amount and by not being able to sort my data that way the cumulative amount does not work.

Comment: If you're having a problem with a query returning the results you need, it would be best to add that to your question. Query constructs can provide the logical order you need regardless of the physical storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQL does not retain the sort.

This is soooo true.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  No ordering.  Get it?

That said, you can sort of impose order on the data.  Here are two methods:

1. You can define a primary key.  The data is physically sorted on the data pages (in SQL Server) based on the primary key.
2. You can define an identity column.  In conjunction with `order by`, the identity column will capture the ordering.

Strictly speaking these have no effect on the result set from a query on the table.  Instead, they are methods for storing the ordering in the data.

What is true about tables being unordered is also true about result sets.  So if you run:

```
Select MemberID, TotalSpend
from SampleTable;
```

The result set is *unordered*.  That means that even with a primary key or an identity column or both, SQL Server can return the rows in whatever order it so desires.  It can even return the data in different orders on different runs.

Fixing this is easy.  If you want the data in a particular order, simply add the following to your query:

```
order by TotalSpend
```

If you have an index on the column, then the sorting would normally use the index (unless the data is very small), so very little overhead would be incurred.

Comment: To suggest to create a clustered index  or add Identity column in order to sort your data is a poor advice I am afraid.

Comment: @M.Ali . . . That is not the intention of the answer.  I thought it was pretty clear originally, but I further clarified it.